# How can I quickly re-enable fn shortcuts that stopped working?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

On 15.04, sometimes (fairly often) my fn shortcuts stop working. The problem is in the OS, they are still able to change brightness, but no notification is displayed and I cannot change the volume with them. I found out that running `ccsm` and enabling and disabling the `commands` plugin is a reliable way to reenable those fn keys. Is there a programatic way I could do the same so I could write a script that would re-enable the shortucts every five minutes and I would not have to worry about this?

I know this is most likely a bug, but I have not noticed any regularity, so I wouldn't know what to report - and I am interested in a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this script that I run upon startup and hourly in cron, it should fix that (since disabling and reenabling compiz commands plugin fixes this and that is what the script does in an ugly way - I am sure the bash could be much better, but it works).

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
a=`gsettings get org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins`
b=`echo $a | sed "s/'commands', //" | sed "s/, 'commands'//"`
c=`echo "${b::-1}, 'commands']"`
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins "$c"
sleep 0.1
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins "$b"
sleep 0.1
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins "$a"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue some days ago. Please see this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622382/ubuntu-15-04-sound-keyboard-terminal-shortcut-stopped-working?noredirect=1#comment884109_622382) and it is again working. The only issue remain left is that I can't see notifications while changing the sound/brightness.

Comment: Hm, that seems related (that bug that is linked there has something to do with gnome-shell, which this uninstalled), but I do not experiene any of your package problems (no complaints, everytihng uninstalls and reinstalls without problems). I will see if it changes tihgs though.

Comment: That solution did not help me actually.