# Ubuntu 15.04 : Sound, keyboard, terminal shortcut stopped working

Tags: unity, sound, keyboard

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. After this, I am facing some weird errors.

1. My shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> stopped working for terminal.
2. Function keys for sound not working anymore.
3. My keyboard settings are not working, not able to switch or use any     other language except English.
4. Unity tweak tool throwing error on startup:

```
     Following Schema is missing:
       org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I remedy this?

Comment: does the shortcut start working if you run `gnome-settings-daemon` in terminal ?

Comment: No, I doesn't work. Even when I ran this command, my touchpad "Click" stopped working, but touchpad buttons and pointer were working successfully

Comment: Are you experiencing this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1427877

Comment: Yes! It is similar. But even if I restart gnome-settings-daemon, it doesn't work, neither on system restart. Also, it when I try to change keyboard and mouse settings from SYSTEM SETTINGS, it just close the settings window on click :(

Comment: I had a similar problem and my solution was to remove guake, which was in conflict with the default terminal

Comment: I have installed guake as well. It has taken over the default keyboard shortcut for terminal, but it works. . . The above problem was that Terminal shortcut was not working at all

Answer (score 9):

Try to turn off or on shortCuts(Commands) in CompizConfig Setting Manager (Icon with keyboards keys <kbd>y</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). This solved my problems with shortcuts in `Unity Ubuntu 15.04`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pilot6, you are wrong.  This does, in fact, provide an answer to exactly the problem that the OP describes.  I was encountering very similar keyboard behavior (Ctrl-Alt-T stopped working, etc), and found that doing as jeti_ suggested completely fixed the problem, without any need to uninstall/reinstall anything.  I highly recommend people try this solution first.

Comment: I just upgraded from 14.04 to 15.04 and my media keys had stopped working. Disabling the Commands CCSM plugin worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @foogod exactly what did you do? What does "Icon with keyboards keys y+z+Ctrl" mean?

Comment: When you open the CompizConfig Settings Manager (/usr/bin/ccsm .. you may need to install the compizconfig-settings-manager package first), there will be an icon shown under the "General" section which says "Commands" next to it, and looks like part of a keyboard (with the "x", "y", and "ctrl" keys visible). Click on that icon and then in the region on the left side you'll see a checkbox for "Enable Commands".  Uncheck and recheck that checkbox (it may take a second or two for it to update when you turn it off or on)

Answer (score 3):

After so much efforts I was able to solve my problem myself. I did the following steps and it worked.

1. Uninstall gnome-settings-daemon`sudo apt-get remove gnome-settings-daemon`
2. uninstall all other packages, which are not required `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. After uninstalling, I tried to install gnome-settings-daemon again using `sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon`
   but it started showing me some broken dependencies issues related to gnome-settings-daemon-schemas.
4. So, I opened **Synaptic Package manager** and reinstalled **gnome-settings-daemon-schemas**.
5. After it, I installed **gnome-Settings-Daemon** from Synaptic package manager and it was successfully installed without any dependency issue.

restarted the system and Everything started working except **Unity Tweak tool** which was now giving me new error that **com.canonical.unity.webapps** is missing. So, I installed `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service`and it worked.

Now, the only problem I am facing is Indicators are missing. like TextEntry change indicator on taskbar, screen brightness change, sound change indicators etc. But everything is working now.

Thanks, I hope my answer will help

Comment: Worked for me also on Ubuntu 15.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also have the problem with the non working Audio function keys after upgrading to 15.04.
I've reassigned them to some other custom keys via System Setttings > Keyboard > Shortcuts. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow_Keys</kbd> now.